# Error appearing but all code same as instructors "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'current'"

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, tetris

I am following along a JS course in which a basic game of tetris is made. The grid has been saved and all tetrominos have been saved. But when I try to get the first Tetromino to appear I get the error,

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'current'`

I searched google for help, but all the information online told me that there must be a previous mistake in my code, which I just can't find.

I have three files all the code was written in VS code and local server opened in edge,

**app.js**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const grid = document.querySelector('.grid')
    let squares = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.grid div'))
    const ScoreDisplay = document.querySelector('#score')
    const StartBtn = document.querySelector('#start-button')
    const width = 10



    //The Tetrominos
    const lTetromino = [
        [1, width+1, width*2+1, 2],
        [width, width+1, width+2, width*2+2],
        [1, width+1, width*2+1, width*2],
        [width, width*2, width*2+1, width*2+2]
      ]
    
      const zTetromino = [
        [0,width,width+1,width*2+1],
        [width+1, width+2,width*2,width*2+1],
        [0,width,width+1,width*2+1],
        [width+1, width+2,width*2,width*2+1]
      ]
    
      const tTetromino = [
        [1,width,width+1,width+2],
        [1,width+1,width+2,width*2+1],
        [width,width+1,width+2,width*2+1],
        [1,width,width+1,width*2+1]
      ]
    
      const oTetromino = [
        [0,1,width,width+1],
        [0,1,width,width+1],
        [0,1,width,width+1],
        [0,1,width,width+1]
      ]
    
      const iTetromino = [
        [1,width+1,width*2+1,width*3+1],
        [width,width+1,width+2,width+3],
        [1,width+1,width*2+1,width*3+1],
        [width,width+1,width+2,width+3]
      ]

    let theTetrominos = [lTetromino, zTetromino, tTetromino, iTetromino, oTetromino]

    let currentPosition = 4
    let current = theTetrominos[0][0]

    console.log(theTetrominos[0][0])

    //draw the first rotation
    function draw()
        current.forEach(index => {
            squares[currentPosition + index].classList.add('tetromino')
        })
    
    draw()

})
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"></link>
    <title>Basic Tetris</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h3>Score:<span id="score">0</span></h3>
    <button id="start-button">Start/Pause</button>

    <div class="grid">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
  </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
.grid {
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.grid div {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
}

.tetromino {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

According to the error message my problem is in the app.js file. I have compared my code to that of the instructors on GitHub, but I came to the conclusion that it is identical. Is there an Error that I didn't spot? Or is there another issue with my code?

All help greatly appreciated,
Stan U.

Comment: You forgot `{`…`}` after `function draw()`. Familiarize yourself with the [function declaration syntax](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#syntax).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: Missing '{}'. Seems somehow, I was so preoccupied on the spelling I forgot about the brackets entirely.

Best Regards,
Stan U.